# What is a probability ensemble?

Tags: probability, cryptography

The definition I have says

*An ensemble index by $I$ is a sequences of random variables indexed by $I$. Namely, any $X = {X_i}_{i \in I}$, where each $X_i$ is a random variable, is an ensemble indexed by $I$.*

How is this different from just a set of random variables?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, a set isn't indexed, it's just a collection of unique elements.

Without context, I don't know why it serves the author's purposes to define this structure as opposed to just considering a set of random variables, but presumably it is helpful for an argument they are making.

Comment: It looks like wikipedia has a very [similar definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_ensemble). Is it possible that { } does not denote a set here and actually implies a sequence?

Comment: It implies an [index set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_set), which is a distinct structure from a set.

Comment: So if the index set is the natural numbers, then the probability ensemble X is just X_1, X_2, X_3, ... ?

Comment: @Dramal Exactly. But it could just as well be $\mathbb{Z}_p$ or the set of points on $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ with some  defined order.